# How to calculate Monero addresses for different account numbers?

Tags: viewkey, sub-address, spend-key, account

Monero accounts and subaddresses are conceptually well illustrated at https://medium.com/@anhdres/how-moneros-accounts-and-subaddresses-work-in-monerujo-4fa7df0a58e4.

And page 125 of [Mastering Monero](https://masteringmonero.com/book/Mastering%20Monero%20First%20Edition%20by%20SerHack%20and%20Monero%20Community.pdf) does a good job of describing how subaddresses associated with account #0 are calculated.

My question is, how are the deterministic Monero public spend and view keys calculated for accounts other than account #0?

Answer (score 1):

Each account is simply another subaddress. Therefore the math is identical to the usual subaddresses calculation - it is still represented by an `i` index in:

PS<sub>**i**</sub> = Hs(pV<sub>0</sub> || **i**) G + PS<sub>0</sub>

*(using Mastering Monero's notation).*

However, it's worth noting that the calculation for the subaddress *secret* key is actually `m = Hs(a || index_major || index_minor)`, and for its *public* key, `M = mG`, where `index_major` is the account index and `index_minor` is the subaddress index. Thus **i** is the concatenation of `index_major || index_minor`.

Therefore the *Master Monero* example is a little misleading. The subaddress, regardless of which account it is in, is actually calculated like:

PS<sub>**ij**</sub> = Hs(pV<sub>0</sub> || **j** || **i**) G + PS<sub>0</sub>

Or in the common notation used in the code and elsewhere:

```
m = Hs(a || index_major || index_minor)
M = mG
D = M + B
```

`D` being your public view and spend keys for account # subaddress #.

Sources: [device_default.cpp#L144](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/b8ab510f238e5a4b9907ea09ed0f364b34ab1ae5/src/device/device_default.cpp#L144) and [device_default.cpp#L198](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/b8ab510f238e5a4b9907ea09ed0f364b34ab1ae5/src/device/device_default.cpp#L198)